# animate two side by side placed divs equal

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs in my body which both have the following css:

```css
#one {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color:#F00;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
}
#two {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color:#FF0;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0px;
}
```

and I would like to animate at any one time one of them to the left or right. While animate the other div should shrink to the width of the other div was animated bigger. My attempt was to do it with `margin` but it does not really work because when animating the divs breaks out!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $sach = $('#one');
    var $archi = $('#two');

    function showSach() {
        $sach.animate({
            marginRight: '500px' 
        });
    }

    function showArchi() {
        $archi.animate({
            marginLeft: '500px' 
        });
    }

    $('#archi_btn').bind('click', showArchi);
    $('#sach_btn').bind('click', showSach);
});
```

I've made a picture for better explaining:

[image: picture]

Comment: Your link returns a 404 error.. :/

Comment: How can you have side-by-side divs when both of them are of width 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the width of the divs instead. Here's a fiddle to get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/992k3/

```
function showSach() {
    $sach.animate({
        width: '74%'
    });
    $archi.animate({
        width: '24%'
    });
}

function showArchi() {
    $sach.animate({
        width: '24%'
    });
    $archi.animate({
        width: '74%'
    });
}
```